# how to solve bugs for the matlab example "fulltosparse.c"

Tags: c, matlab, mex, sparse-matrix

This file is in `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\extern\examples\refbook`. After mex it, I used :

```
aa = [1 2 3 ; 4 5 6]
fulltosparse(aa)
```

At the first time, the command maybe works. But try `fulltosparse(aa)` for more times. You will find it will crash. Could anyone tell me why ?

```
mex -largeArrayDims fulltosparse.c
aa = [1 2 3; 4  5 7];
fulltosparse(aa);
fulltosparse(aa);
fulltosparse(aa);
fulltosparse(aa);
fulltosparse(aa);
fulltosparse(aa);
```

Comment: Are you using visual studio as a C compiler to run mex files, if yes, then go to Tools -> Attach to process -> Attach to MATLAB. Then place a breakpoint in the c code in visual studio. Run MATLAB code. You should be able to debug.

Comment: @Parag Don't forget to run `mex` with the `-g` flag to include debugging information.

Comment: Yes that is absolutely necessary. I missed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears is a bug in `fulltosparse.c` with the computation of the new `nzmax` when additional space for storage of non-zeros is required by the sparse matrix.

At each non-zero row `i` and column `j` of the `m` rows and `n` columns, respectively, of the `full` source matrix (the `k`th non-zero element), a check is made (`k>=nzmax`) to ensure there is sufficient storage space in the sparse matrix data buffers (`sr`, `si` and `irs`). If there is not enough space for more elements, the buffers are expanded via `mxRealloc` with enough space for an increased `nzmax` number of non-zero elements.

The problem is how it computes the *new* `nzmax`:

```
mwSize oldnzmax = nzmax;
percent_sparse += 0.1;
nzmax = (mwSize)ceil((double)m*(double)n*percent_sparse);

/* make sure nzmax increases atleast by 1 */
if (oldnzmax == nzmax)
    nzmax++;
```

The function starts with an initial `percent_sparse = 0.2`, which for the `2x3` full matrix `aa` corresponds to `nzmax = ceil(6*0.2) = 2`, and begins looping through rows (fastest) and columns. Here's what goes wrong:

- At `k=2` (the third element in MATLAB indexing; `i=0`, `j=1`), it needs to expand the buffers for the first time, and the above code runs prior to reallocation. `oldnzmax` is 2. `percent_sparse` is increased to 0.3, giving `nzmax=ceil(6*0.3)=2`. Since `oldnzmax == nzmax`, it just increments (`nzmax++`) and reallocates for `nzmax=3`. OK.
- At `k=3` (the fourth element; `i=1`, `j=1`), it goes through a similar path, increasing `percent_sparse` to 0.4, computes `nzmax=ceil(6*0.4)=3` and increments `nzmax` to 4.
- **When it reaches `k=4`** (the fifth element; `i=0`, `j=2`), the loop iteration starts with `nzmax=4` and `percent_sparse=0.4`. By this point it is very clear that `percent_sparse` hasn't kept up: `(nzmax=4)/6 = 0.666 > percent_sparse=0.4`. Now the bug becomes obvious when `percent_sparse += 0.1;` gives only 0.5 and **the new `nzmax=ceil(6*0.5)=3`, which is less than `oldnzmax=4`!**.
- Disaster: with `k=4` and `nzmax=3`, it reallocates the sparse matrix buffers (`sr`, `si` and `irs`), and overruns both buffers:

  ```
  sr[k] = pr[i];  // k=4, sr is length 3
  irs[k] = i;     //      irs is length 3
  ```

The buffers were actually *reduced in size*. However, even if the test was changed to `oldnzmax >= nzmax`, the buffers would still not increase in size because **`nzmax` is computed from a `percent_sparse` that is not being incremented fast enough**.  There are two changes that I think are needed. First, both the test and the increment need to handle the case when `nzmax<oldnzmax`:

```
if (oldnzmax >= nzmax)
    nzmax = oldnzmax+1;
```

Second, just for good measure, `percent_sparse` should be properly updated when the conditional is true and `nzmax` gets incremented rather than computed from `percent_sparse`:

```
if (oldnzmax >= nzmax)
{
    nzmax = oldnzmax+1;
    percent_sparse = (double)nzmax/((double)m*(double)n);
}
```

Comment: +1 nice debugging, I just arrived at the same conclusion after stepping into the code.. I was going to suggest doubling the capacity each time, instead of using percentage increments. We can always reallocate `sr/si/irs` at the end of the function to remove excess and reducing `nzmax` to exactly fit the nonzeros values, that is if you are really short on space :)

Comment: Funny enough the corresponding Fortran version (`loadsparse.F` file) will simply truncate the values if the matrix is more than 20% sparse (plus it completely ignores the complex case)

Comment: That is funny.  Whoever wrote the FORTRAN example was apparently quite lazy or didn't have a good handle on the language. There are FORTRAN versions of both `mxSetNzMax` and `mxRealloc`...